# Glassfish and Verisign Trial Test Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, certificate, keytool

I have glassfish 3.1.2 and need to configure SSL, so I refered [This site](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/how_to_use_verisign_cert). Everything seems to be ok until I get to the last command

```
-import -v -alias myservkey -file myservkeyveri.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

I get

> /home/user/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/keytool -import -v -alias myservkey -file intex.cer -keystore > keystore.jks
>   Enter keystore password:
>   Enter key password for 
>   keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
>   java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
>     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.establishCertChain(KeyTool.java:2618)
>     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.installReply(KeyTool.java:1870)
>     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:807)
>     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
>     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)

can somebody help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use different aliases when you import these root certs from genkey.

when you use keytool -genkey command then it generates a keystore and a key. Have you made sure that the cert which you are importing is in PEM format (PEM certs can be opened in any text editor)

Comment: I am not sure it's PEM or not, how do we check that ?, But I still can open the csr from text editor, we have --Begin Certificate-- and --End Certificate--

Comment: Please remove the keystore passwords from your output.try this.and also refer this.http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=505